# Delphi - DirectX - OSD/Screen Overlay

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Good evening guys,
I'm currently working on an NVIDIA GPU temperature monitor in Delphi 2010. It's also gonna provide system information from WMI.

At present, i'm working on a few different OSD (On-Screen Display) methods for different situations. I've got 2 methods already, but i need another specifically for games.

What i'm wanting to do is display an overlay or OSD with some text using Direct2D or Direct3D. DLL injection is risky, not to mention quite tricky to perfect. As you can imagine, i'm trying to overlay it into games, but overlaying it anywhere would be just as good.

As you can imagine, using Direct2D or Direct3D to overlay it would be much better. Hooking would be one idea but again, that would likely lead to requiring me to inject code too.

Essentially, i want the simplest method of displaying text on screen that doesn't have a hefty performance loss, and doesn't flicker when the screen refreshes (i.e. a new frame is rendered). I'd love to be able to draw images as well (since i include graphs in my app, outputting those would be a bonus but outputting the text is the major task here).

I honestly don't mind if i need to hook and/or inject, but i've no experience with doing so and absolutely would need a lot of help with that. Doing something similar to what MSI Afterburner or FRAPS do would be exactly what i'm after.

I also lack any knowledge of DX programming or design, so again, heavy help is needed there. I've got most of the app designed and working, and it's a matter of finishing up this one large task, and cleaning up the other smaller parts.

Any ideas?

**Edited:** Reduced the number of paragraphs for easier reading. Reducing it more would likely not explain the point enough. For people seeing the edited version, i did do heavy research but yielded no results.

**Edited:** No one got any more input? Would it instead be possible to use a DLL written in another language to output the OSD, and simply pass my parameters to it? If so, how would i go about doing so and is there any sample code in any language i could use to work with?

Comment: Toyed with a similar thing several years ago (for very different purpose). I have to say it's not the easiest thing in the world to acheive (even though I HAVE experience with OpenGL, DirectX (2D and 3D), and video game development. Overlays are pain. Hoping someone provides a nice solution (I can benefit from it too). +1'd the question. Recommend reducing the paragraphs if you can, though!

Comment: Thanks LaKraven. I didn't imagine it'd be easy to do. However, i'm an OCD developer, and i don't put an app out until i'm happy with it. If i don't want to use it myself because it's subpar to existing apps, i don't feel like i can put it out on the world unless it's just designed for one specific purpose.

I did reduce the amount of context in the original question though :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [Taksi](http://taksi.sourceforge.net/). It is sort of an open source FRAPS. And yes, code injection and hooking is involved. And well, written in C++.

Comment: Thanks "iamjoosy", that's something i guess. Building in RAD Studio 2010 would give me the option to work with it, but i'm still preferring Delphi for this project. I still +'d it though since it's worth looking into.